# Swift indexOf, == operator override not getting called

Tags: swift, pfobject

I am getting frustrated with how Swift handles equality. Or I'm just missing something. How come these 2 `indexOf` DOESN'T work the same way?

```
let first = self.objects.indexOf(object) //This returns nil
let second = self.objects.indexOf{$0 == object} //This returns the index
```

My == override:

```
func ==(lhs: MyObject, rhs: MyObject) -> Bool {
    return lhs.someProperty == rhs.someProperty
}
```

The == override doesn't get called in the first indexOf. Why is that so? This feels really dangerous.

(MyObject is a subclass of PFObject (Parse.com objects). I don't know if this is what's messing this up.)

Comment: Is `self.object` a `[MyObject]` or something else (like a `[ParentOfMyObject]`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Object` is subclass of `PFObject`, and `PFObject` is subclass of `NSObject`, and `NSObject` already confirm to `Equatable` by using the `isEqual` method to implement. So your == operator override is not working. You should override the `isEqual` method. (To be honest, it's horrible :(

sample code:

```
class Object: NSObject {
    var value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let obj = object as? Object else { return false }
        return self.value == obj.value
    }
}

// If your class is not inherit from any ObjC class:
//extension Object: Equatable {}
//func ==(lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
//    return lhs.value == rhs.value
//}

let c = Object(value: 3)
let objs = [Object(value: 1), Object(value: 2), Object(value: 3)]

let index = objs.indexOf(c)
let index2 = objs.indexOf { $0 == c }
print(index) // Optional(2)
print(index2) // Optional(2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why apple does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

The second `indexOf` method that you are using allows you to define a closure to indicate object equality (like you have already done). The first one according to the documentation:

> Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if value is not found.

Where `value` is the object you are passing as the parameter. Without seeing the implementation of this version I can only assume they compare if the two objects are equal in every way (all properties match). So in your case, if you only consider the objects equal if the `someProperty`s match, then you should be using the closure method with your overloaded operator.

Comment: So we don't know what indexOf is using as comparison? :(

Comment: Well Swift is open source now so I'm sure you could find it if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
static func == (left: MyClass, right: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return left.attribute1 == right.attribute1
}

override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let right = object as? MyClass else {
        return false
    }
    // call the == from above
    // why couldn't apple do this ???
    // 
    return self == right
}
```